# Why is the declaration *(*(arr+1)+2) not working when I am passing the a 2d array to a function (tes).t

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>

int test(int *x);

void main(){

    int arr[2][3], a;

    arr[1][2] = 2;
    printf("%d\n", test((int *)arr));
    printf("%d\n", *(*(arr+1)+2));
}

int test(int *prr){

    int a;
    a = *(*(prr+1)+2);
    return a;
}
```

The above code is giving me the following error:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  a = *( *(prr+1)+2);

   ^
```

but the same declaration works in the main function:

```
printf("%d\n", *( *(arr+1)+2)).
```

Also when I replace it with `*((arr+1*3) + 2)`, 3 *being the size of 2nd dimension*, in the function test, it worked and I could not understand how ??? I really want to know the reason. please help!!!

And why is their a need to type cast a 2D array, but not 1D array when passing to a function.

I used the help of http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/, but the reason was not there.

Comment: you are passing a `int *`, which is not a 2d array. You have to pass a 2d array, if you want to use it: http://ideone.com/KbGEFg

Comment: @JimLewis a 2d array and a `int **` are not compatible.

Comment: I have update my answer :) I hope you understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

In `main` function `arr` is an array of arrays of `int`. `*(*(arr+1)+2)` is equivalent to `*(arr[1] + 2) = arr[1][2]`. `arr[1]` is an array and will decay to pointer to first element `arr[1][0]`.

In test, `prr` is a pointer to `int`. `*(prr+1)+2` is equivalent to `*(prr[1] + 2)`. `prr[1]` is an `int`. This makes the expression `prr[1] + 2` an `int`. Operand of unary `*` operator must be a pointer variable.

Change function prototype to

```
int test(int x[][3]);
```

and make function call as

```
printf("%d\n", test(arr));
```

Comment: what should I do then, and why *((arr+1*3) + 2) is working ?

Comment: `prr+1*3 + 2` is of type `int *` and dereferencing it will yield an `int` value.

Comment: sorry I don't get it

Comment: My previous comment had typo. I meant `*( (prr+1*3) + 2 )`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a quick short lesson on arrays and pointers.

Thumb rule 1: Arrays and pointers are almost always interchangable but there are exceptions!

Taking a 1-D array, we can declare it like this :-

```
int arr[10];
```

This declares a variable named `arr` which can hold 10 integer elements.

I can similarly use the pointer notation to represent this array using a pointer variable or by using the array name (`arr`) itself.

```
printf ("%d", arr[2]); // Array method : will print out the third element, indexing starts from 0
```

Thumb rule 2: Array name(be it 1D 2D 3D 4D) always decays into a  pointer or an address.

```
printf ("%lu", arr) //will print out the base address of the array, i.e address of the first element
```

How to print the value using a pointer ? Simply, dereference it using `*` operator.

```
printf("%d", *arr) //Pointer notation - will print the first value
```

How to reference the array using another variable?

```
 int *ptr = arr; //Pointer notation - just simply write the array name as it decays into an address

printf("%d", *ptr); //Pointer notation - prints the first element
```

Many people say **int *ptr** is pointer to an array.

**In reality it's not.** It's actually a pointer to an integer not an array. Why?

Because in the first place we are storing the address of the first integer of the array and then we can traverse it by incrementing the pointer. So, in real pointer is storing the address of an integer(First integer).

Now, coming to 2D arrays :-

Declaration:-

```
int arr[2][3]; // arrays of 2 rows and 3 columns, total 6 elements
```

Same above rules implies :-

```
printf("%d", arr[0][1]); //prints the second element of the first row.

printf("%lu", arr) //prints the base address of the 2D array
```

Coming to Pointer Notation :-

```
printf("%d", *(*(arr + 0) + 1); // how this works?
```

arr contains the address. Adding a integer to it with make you jump to that row.

```
arr + 1 // gives the second row, i.e. arr is currently pointing to the first element of second row.
```

Now, further adding an integer to it, will make you skip to that specified column in that particular row.

```
((arr + 1) // second row  +  2 ) // will you skip to third element of the second row
```

This is the implicit pointer notation that language gives you, when you choose to treat the array name as a pointer.

Now coming to your problem : - Explicit Pointer Notation:-

What are you trying to achieve is, storing the base address of the 2D array in a pointer.

How to correctly do that ?

```
int (*ptr)[3]; //reading it goes like this - ptr is a pointer to a 1D array of 3 ints
```

The 3 here specifies the number of columns your 2D array has.

So what it is doing is, trying to store the base address of **first** 1D array of that 2D array (which means 0th row base address) into the pointer.

The rest remains the same.

```
int (*ptr)[3] = arr; // storing the 2D array in ptr
```

Now, you can use it as a normal pointer(Pointer notation applies on it)

```
(ptr + 1) //now ptr is pointer to the Second 1D array of that 2D array or you can say to the second row's first element.
```

Another way you can catch an array in a function is like this:-

I use it very less though.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[2][2];
    fun(arr);
}

void fun(int catch[][])
{


}


// This is simple to understand and as well as to relate. Now, again catch can be used as pointer or as an array. It depends on you :)

void fun1(int (*ptr)[2])
{
      //my way
printf("%d", ptr[1][1]);
printf("%d", *(*(ptr + 1) + 1));

//answer will be the same
}

//Ptr now contains that 2D array base address, again can be used as an array or a pointer :)
```

Comment: what should I write in the declaration of my test function ?

Comment: void fun1(int (*ptr)[2]) & void fun(int catch[][]) both will work. You can have it either ways.

Comment: no I mean the declaration above the main : int test( int *);,

Comment: It will be int test(int (*ptr)[3]) or int test (int ptr[ ][ ]) and try to think on it. Read the answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

in function `test(int *prr)` `prr` points to a integer not a array.
so `*(Prr+1)` is a integer, but '*' unary operator is only applied to pointers.

Answer (score -1):

In you function `main` `arr` is a 2-d array of `int` and thus, this works -

```
 printf("%d\n", *(*(arr+1)+2));  // you dereference it twice to get value
```

But in your function `test`, parameter is of type `int *` and therefore , this expression -

```
  a = *( *(prr+1)+2);    // prr is of type int *
```

gives error as you try to dereference `int *` twice. There is only one level of indirection , so you need to dereference once. Also, you could achieve same by passing 2-d array directly without cast and it would work.

Something like this -

```
int test(int **prr){
    // you code
}
```

and in `main` you can call it like this -

```
int x = test(arr);
```

Comment: what should be the declaration of function test

Comment: @user20395 I have mentioned the type which could be used for parameter in answer.